# Tomcat 7 - HTTPOnly - Bad Set-Cookie header - No '=' found for token

Tags: java, tomcat7, setcookie, httponly

I found an issue in a client using Tomcat 7.0.50.

It says, while consuming a java WebService from SoapUI:

```
status HTTP 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Bad Set-Cookie header: JSESSIONID=CDB8F6AAE5CF6DF2FD70359DFF4B7725; Path=/geotrib/; HttpOnly
No '=' found for token starting at position 61(-10001)
```

In Tomcat 6 this does not happens, because "httponly" is true by default in tomcat 7.

But how can this be? We are getting this error on the very Tomcat that writes the flag.

Any help is much appreciated.

Best regards,
    Federico.

Comment: First thing I would suggest is to use the latest Tomcat 7.  See if that helps.  After that, update your post with the full HTTP request you're sending and the response that you get.  This should help to replicate and debug this further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your http request/response contains "HttpOnly" in its header. It appears to be that this value is not supported by application servers anymore. In order to fix this I wrote a workaround where "HttpOnly" is removed from the response on a server side.

```
    String header = resp.getHeader("Set-Cookie");
    if (header != null && header.endsWith("HttpOnly")) {
        resp.setHeader("Set-Cookie", header.substring(0, header.length() - 8));
    }
```

But the best solution is to remove "HttpOnly" from the header on the http client side.